# How to add rules to the topology from a .rul in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, topology, rule-based

I am trying to create a new topology using and ArcPy script and I have a lot of rules inside a .rul archive. The function to do that is:

```
arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(out_topo, rule_type, in_fc1, subtype1, in_fc2, subtype2)
```

The main fact is that I don't know if I can simply add the .rul archive as a "rule_type" or maybe I have to code a loop to iterate every topology rule and fc related inside the .rul archive.